# scrollIntoViewIfNeeded script not working with protractor

Tags: javascript, typescript, dom, protractor, automated-tests

I'm using protractor to develop an automated web test.

Sometimes, I want to scroll an element into view before clicking on it ( which makes sense ) and I do this with the "scrollIntoView" script.

This doesn't always work when I scroll down because a banner that appears at the bottom when the account is not validated, and it covers the element.

I executed elmement.scrollIntoViewIfNeeded(true) in the browser console and it works like a charm, whether its for scrolling UP or DOWN.

The problem is, when I use it in my tests, it doesn't work.

Here's a code snippet.

```ts
         /**
         * Scrolls the element into view
         * */
        async scrollIntoView() {
            await browser.executeScript('arguments[0].scrollIntoViewIfNeeded(true)', this.webElement.getWebElement());
        }
```

I also made a class named Button to represent elements that have the "button" tag in the DOM, here's the code snippet as well.

```ts
/**
 * A class that handles actions on buttons.
 * */
export class Button extends WebComponent {

    /**
     * @param webElementText Text that the web element contains.
     * @param locatorType Locator type of the web element to search for.
     * @param locator Locator of the web element to search for.
     * @param parentElement Parent Web Component if it exists.
     */
    constructor(webElementText, locatorType, locator, parentElement: WebComponent = null) {
        super(webElementText, locatorType, locator, parentElement);
    }

    /**
     * Clicks on the WebElement found
     * The click can be done with either JavaScript or with an interaction with the UI.
     * @param usingJavaScript {boolean} Boolean to decide whether to use JavaScript for the click or a UI interaction.
     */
    async click(usingJavaScript = false) {
        if (usingJavaScript) {
            await this.isPresent();
            await browser.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", await this.webElement.getWebElement());
        }

        else {
            await this.isPresent();
            await this.scrollIntoView();
            await this.isVisible();
            await this.isClickable();
            await this.webElement.click();
        }
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 assumptions why this can't work:

- you call `click()` without `await`
- `this.webElement.getWebElement()` - something is wrong with the locator

Other than that, everything looks good to me.

If you can't make it work, try my method, which works for me

```
    /**
     *  Scrolls to passed element and then Y pixels down by injecting js scroll() in the context of window
     *  @param      {ElementFinder}     $element        Locator of element
     *  @param      {number}            [offsetY=0]     Offset by Y axis (how much extra pixels to scroll)
     *  @param      {number}            [sleep=200]     wait after scroll to allow scrolling animation to complete
     *  @return     {Promise}
     */
    scroll: async ($element, offsetY = 0, sleep = 200) => {
        await browser.executeScript(`arguments[0].scrollIntoView({block: "center"});`, $element.getWebElement());
        await browser.sleep(sleep);
    }
```

Note that `{block: "center"}` makes it scroll until the element is in the middle of page and does solve problems when footers/headers are overlapping it

Comment: I am for sure using await witch click, so that's not the issue here I guess.
What could possibly be wrong with the locator?

I'll try your solution tomorrow and let you know.
Thanks @Sergey Pleshakov

Comment: block: "center" worked just fine !  Thanks
Btw, I implemented a wait to be sure that an animation stopped and I want to share it with you. But there are I won't fit into a comment characters-wise.

Comment: `async isStable() {
        await browser.wait(
            this.compareElementPositions()
            , this._elapsedTime,
            'Element ${this._locator} is not stable after ${this._elapsedTime} ms');
    }
    async compareElementPositions() {
        let pos1 = await this.webElement.getLocation();
        await browser.sleep(200);
        let pos2 = await this.webElement.getLocation();
        return await pos1 === pos2;
    }`

Comment: Oh thank you, that's a good idea to check for element's stability!

Comment: You're welcome, the only thing left to check is determine how much time the browser should sleep. A part from that, it works just fine for me